# Is it possible to read assets in Windows Store app using stdio functions?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm porting an existing app written in standard C++ to Windows 8. I've tried using WRL for reading assets but it is big PITA and doesn't fit in multithreading model I'm using. C stdio functions seem to work too on the development machine but will they still work after publishing app to Windows Store?

The code below obtains a full path to asset on the file system and uses it to open a FILE:

```
auto uri = ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png");
concurrency::create_task(Windows::Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri))
.then([](Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ file)
{
    FILE* f;
    auto path = file->Path->Data();
    auto e = _wfopen_s(&f, path, L"rb");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Store apps will always have read access to their installation directory and read/write access to their local data directory.  Files at these locations can be accessed with stdio functions, even after publishing the app to the store.

The known folders that require an entry in the manifest file to access, such as the Documents Library, can't be accessed with stdio.

The installation and local data folders for an app are:

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation
Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder
```

Sample for obtaining the file system path for and opening an asset file in the installed location:

```
std::wstring wpath = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path->Data();
wpath += L"\\Assets\\Logo.png";

FILE* f = nullptr;
errno_t e = _wfopen_s(&f, wpath.c_str(), L"rb");
```

These locations are also accessible with stdio for Windows Phone apps.  Windows Store apps can also access the RoamingFolder and TemporaryFolder with stdio, which are not available for Windows Phone apps.  More information can be found on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx